# Unity error marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a character controller for unity. I am new to C# programming, I have written some code,

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomPorpertyDrawer(typeof(AxisKeys))]
public class PlayerAxisKeysDrawer: PropertyDrawer{

    public override void onGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        //don't indent
        int indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

        //ensure override works on entire property
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        //label
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

        //set position rects;
        Rect posLabel = new Rect(position.x, position.y, 15, position.height);
        Rect posField = new Rect(position.x + 20, position.y, 50, position.height);

        Rect negLabel = new Rect(position.x, position.y, 15, position.height);
        Rect negField = new Rect(position.x + 20, position.y, 50, position.height);

        GUIContent posGUI = new GUIContent("+");
        GUIContent negGUI = new GUIContent("-");

        //draw fields
        EditorGUI.LabelField(posLabel, posGUI);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(posField, property.FindPropertyRelative("positive"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.LabelField(negLabel, negGUI);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(negField, property.FindPropertyRelative("negative"), GUIContent.none);

        //reset indent
        EditorGUI.indentlevel = indent;

        //end property
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

But getting this error.  Can anybody help in thsis?

```
 error CS0115: `PlayerAxisKeysDrawer.onGUI(UnityEngine.Rect, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty, UnityEngine.GUIContent)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake, change `OnInspectecorGUI` to `OnInspectorGUI` and it should work :)

Comment: ok thanks, I have a same error in another file. But In that case i think its not because of mistake.

Comment: I will select your answer for the first one.

Comment: @CreativeDip it's `OnGUI` not `onGUI`. C# is case sensitive